# Show hint on the Selected Item with content of It's value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a `select` control which will show numbers of statute.

However to the standard user only number does not mean anything ( on the other hand if I create `select` control which contains text of those statues it would be totally unreadable).

I want to show `div` with hint which will appear on the `mouse over` the selected item. But to be honest I have some problems with it.

Here is my `select control`:

```
<select name="dropdn" class="mydpdn">
    <option title='Some description for the ASX-1/1'>ASX-1/1</option>
    <option title='Some description for the ASX-1/2'>ASX-1/2</option>
    <option title='Some description for the ASX-1/3'>ASX-1/3</option>
    <option title='Some description for the ASX-1/4'>ASX-1/4</option>
    <option title='Some description for the ASX-1/5'>ASX-1/5</option>
    <option title='Some description for the AED-1/1'>AED-1/1</option>
    <option title='Some description for the AED-1/2'>AED-1/2</option>
    <option title='Some description for the AED-1/3'>AED-1/3</option>
</select>
```

`Title` tag is the only way I can think of. But this solution make `hint` appear with some delay and additionally I cannot (or don't knew how) create `CSS` for this hint to look more user friendly.

Can anyone give me a hint how I can improve this code?

Comment: You can't style a `title` through normal `CSS`. You will have to look for a javascript workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the title attributes feature since it is the implementation of the browser. You need to use third party tooltip kind of stuff for your issue. One such plugin is [JQuery tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).